# Jsf inputText onkeyup event handler

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

In PrimeFace's `inputText`, I need to call function ‍‍‍`f1()` when any key is pressed.

To implement this, in `xhtml` file I have:

```
<p:inputText id="userName" onkeyup="#{myBean.f1()}" >
```

And in my `MyBean.java` i have declared this function:

```
public void f1()
{
// somecode
}
```

‌But this code throws an exception:

> javax.faces.FacesException: javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml
>   @103,191 onkeyup="#{MyBean.f1()}": java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to call a java method you should use `p:ajax event` instead of `onkeyup` attribute

```
<p:inputText id="userName">
     <p:ajax event="keyup" listener="#{myBean.f1}"></p:ajax>
</p:inputText>
```

> onkeyup : Client side callback to execute when a key is released over
>   input element.

in other words onkeyup is for calling js functions like `onkeyup="alert('hello')"`

about the exception you got : its cause you page tried to execute the `f1` method on page load and not on keyup event - for example if you `f1` method would have return a string that string would replace the `#{myBean.f1()}` and your generated page would look like this:

```
... onkeyup="string value returned from f1 method" ...
```